# Искажение дат при загрузке - Excel

Tags: excel

Вопрос. С оракловского сервера через интерфейс выгружаю информацию, в ТХТ(иного формата нет), для того что бы загрузить информацию в эксель, даты находятся в формате "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS", но при загрузке в свой столбец на лист НЕКОТОРЫЕ даты меняют формат на "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ чч:мм:сс", в связи с тем что между датой и временем появляется лишний пробел. Хотя самой выгрузке лишних пробелов нет. Подскажите как решить эту проблему чтоб не обрабатывать дополнительно этот столбец?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *в связи с тем что между датой и временем появляется лишний пробел. Хотя самой выгрузке лишних пробелов нет.* В выгрузке пробела нет, но он появляется... Вам не кажется, что фраза какая-то слабовменяемая? *при загрузке в свой столбец на лист НЕКОТОРЫЕ даты меняют формат на "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ чч:мм:сс", в связи с тем что между датой и временем появляется лишний пробел.* Попробуйте найти зависимость между значением и фактом конвертации - не должен один пробел так влиять... опять же попробуйте при выгрузке с Оракла подобрать текстовый формат даты такой, чтобы ненужных разногласий не возникало.

Comment: Преобразование происходит при загрузке дат из *txt* в *Excel*? Чем производится операция? Попробуйте вручную открыть *txt* в *Excel*. Та же ошибка? Некоторые даты - какие? Покажите пример исходных данных и их же после выгрузки.

Comment: @vikttur, Да, из txt в Excel. Загрузку произвожу через Данные - Из текста - Выбор файла - С разделителями( | ) - Готово.

При открытии плоского файла все корректно. Лишнего пробела нет.

В тхт дата выглядит 2019-01-31 11:30:31 после 31.01.2019  11:30. , при том что другие даты в нужном формате

Comment: Т.е. в `Excel` в одном столбце получается разный формат даты? Странно... *Данные - Из текста - Выбор файла - С разделителями( | ) - Готово* - перед Готово пройдите два шага (*Далее-Далее*) и укажите формат данных `Дата`. Поле открытия в Excel посмотрите - там точно даты? Проверить: `=ЕЧИСЛО(A1)` Если *ЛОЖЬ* - в ячейке нет даты, там текст

Comment: @vikttur, делал так. напротив даты : ГМД. Формула показывает ИСТИНА, там где формат который мне не нужен и с пробелом. 31.01.2019 11:30
Изменяю формат данных на ГГГГ-ММ-ДД чч:мм:сс, даты становятся парвильного формата. но всеравно с лишним пробелом.

Comment: Проверили? Нет текстовых? Поверка проще (если перед этим в столбце не применялось выравнивание): растянуть столбец н достаточную ширину. Нормальные даты должны разместиться в ячейке справа, текст - слева.

Comment: @vikttur, добавил картинку для понимания.

Comment: Какой результат-то должен быть? То, что слева, или то, что справа? И добавьте фрагмент исходного текстового файла. Бросается в глаза, что там где "ложь" несуществующие даты - 57-е января, 44-е декабря.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никто не мешал показать данные сразу. Избежали бы лишней переписки и траты времени как своего, так и отвечающих.

Зря Вы плюсики поставили там, где ЛОЖЬ - нет там даты. Покажите календарь, в котором есть 51 декабря 2018 г., 48 января 2019 г....

Нормальные даты отображаются в том формате, который указан в *Excel* в настройках.

=============================

Поле открытия в *Excel* смотреть - там точно даты? Проверить:

```
=ЕЧИСЛО(A1)
```

Если *ЛОЖЬ* - в ячейке нет даты, там текст.

Поверка проще (если перед этим в столбце не применялось выравнивание): растянуть столбец на достаточную ширину. Нормальные даты должны разместиться в ячейке справа, текст - слева.

Если даты остались в текстовом формате, искать, что мешает - лишние символы, некорректные данные...

Comment: Залет.....Вот этого я и не заметил. Благодарю. Теперь все понятно что с ним.